# Scheduled WebJob doesn't invoke function as scheduled

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs

I'm new at the Azure Webjob concept. I'm trying to create a WebJob which will be triggered.

**Program.cs**

```
static void Main()
{
    var config = new JobHostConfiguration();

    if (config.IsDevelopment)
    {
        config.UseDevelopmentSettings();
    }

    var host = new JobHost(config);
    host.Call(typeof(Functions).GetMethod("MyMethod"));
    host.RunAndBlock();

}
```

**Function.cs**

```
[NoAutomaticTrigger]
public static void MyMethod()
{
   //Logic
}
```

I can see that My WebJob is running, but only invoking the function at the very beginning of the deployment. I can run the function via using Function Invocation Log.

If I'm not mistaken it should invoke the function as I scheduled right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are triggering the job at startup with this line `host.RunAndBlock();`

If you want it to be triggered by a schedule, 
just add a `settings.job` file to your webjob project containing the cron time you want

For example

```
{
  "schedule": "0 0 * * * *"
}
```

Then in you program.cs, just use

```
using (var host = new JobHost(config))
{
    host.Call(typeof(Functions).GetMethod("MyMethod"));
}
```

Deploy the code, don't forget to copy the `settings.job` to your output directory, and the cron setting should be visual under your application webjob view from the portal

Answer (score 0):

> If I'm not mistaken it should invoke the function as I scheduled right?

What schedule? You didn't configure any schedule. The only thing you're doing is calling `MyMethod` once (by getting the  method using reflection!) and then you're calling `RunAndBlock` on `host`.

Have a look at Run Background tasks with WebJobs in Azure App Service > [Create a scheduled WebJob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-create-web-jobs#CreateScheduledCRON)

You could have a look at [Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/). That might help, too.

Comment: I scheduled it at the portal where I can create WebJob on a WebApp.